Ubuntu (Studio) 24.10 desktop freezes when attempting to wake up from sleep/suspend
The Problem
Whenever I try to wake up the PC from sleep/suspend mode, the system initially appears to respond, but then the screen freezes & doesn't respond to anything I do. At this point, the only way out appears to be to force-shutdown the machine by holding the power button for 5 seconds, then starting it up again.
This occurs regardless of whether the sleep was triggered manually or automatically after enough inactivity, and regardless of whether the wakeup attempt was done by moving the mouse, hitting the keyboard, or pressing the power button. Sometimes it visibly brings up the login screen again, but sometimes (I think if I'm already logged in), it shows a screen that's entirely black except for the mouse cursor. In any case, neither moving the mouse nor typing on the keyboard produces any visible response at all.
System
I'm running Ubuntu Studio 24.10, but if I remember correctly, the problem was also manifesting when I was still on 24.04.x.
My hardware is as follows:
Motherboard: ASUS Z790 GAMING WIFI7
CPU: Intel Core i9-14900K (x86_64)
GPU: AMD Radeon RX 7900XT
Storage: 8 TB SSD
RAM: 96 GB NVMe DDR5
Solutions I Have Already Tried (to no avail)

When frozen, switching to a different TTY using Ctrl+Alt+F2–F6: It simply doesn't do anything at all.

(Incidentally, when I'm not frozen, Ctrl+Alt+F2 in particular, rather than taking me to a new shell session, displays an entirely-black screen with just a mouse cursor that's very similar to the one I sometimes see during the wakeup freezes, except that I can actually move the mouse around, as well as return to the main graphical session using Ctrl+Alt+F1.)


Limiting the CPU's maximum C-state in GRUB config: I've tried creating a new file in /etc/default/grub.d/ and adding the line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="$GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT intel_idle.max_cstate=1", then running sudo update-grub and rebooting. I've also tried changing the variable name to processor.max_cstate and the value to 4. No permutations of the aforementioned steps appear to make a difference in the end.
Increasing swap space: The size of /swap.img was already 8 GB, but I increased it to 10 GB in accordance with advice I read stating that the swap file should be the square root of total system RAM. In retrospect, I'm not certain what difference I even expected this to make in the first place.
Disabling systemd session freezing: Following other advice online, I experimented with adding the following environment variables for configuration of systemd 256+:

Created /etc/systemd/system/systemd-suspend.service.d/freeze_fix.conf:
[Service]
Environment="SYSTEMD_SLEEP_FREEZE_USER_SESSIONS=false"


Created /etc/systemd/system/systemd-sleep.service.d/ as a symlink to /etc/systemd/system/systemd-suspend.service.d.
Created /etc/systemd/system/systemd-homed.service.d/freeze_fix.conf:
[Service]
Environment="SYSTEMD_HOME_LOCK_FREEZE_SESSION=false"






(The people I've seen post similar issues on the internet in the past have often been told to check their system logs in /var/log/syslog and/or the output of journalctl (or more specifically, journalctl -b -1). The initial versions of this post had the results of those logs from the suspension process pasted below, but I have since removed them because they only contained messages from the suspension process itself rather than the process of waking up again, which is when the actual issue occurs.)

I finally found the source of the issue! Turns out that for some reason, the issue only occurs for me when Bluetooth is enabled. While this indicates a deeper issue with the way that systemd and my network card interact with each other during sleep/suspension routines, it also reveals a very straightforward workaround: simply ensure that Bluetooth is disabled whenever sleep/suspension is triggered.
The cleanest way to do this was by creating a small systemd service that uses rfkill to check whether Bluetooth is unblocked (i.e. on) or not, and if so, blocks it for the duration of the sleep/suspension, then unblocks it again when the system wakes back up.
Created the unit file /etc/systemd/system/bt_workaround.service:
[Unit]
Description=Bluetooth Workaround for Suspension
Before=sleep.target suspend.target hybrid-sleep.target suspend-then-hibernate.target
StopWhenUnneeded=yes

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecCondition=/usr/bin/env sh -c 'test "$(rfkill -no SOFT list bluetooth)" = unblocked'
ExecStart=/usr/bin/env rfkill block bluetooth
ExecStop=/usr/bin/env rfkill unblock bluetooth

[Install]
RequiredBy=sleep.target suspend.target hybrid-sleep.target suspend-then-hibernate.target

Ran sudo systemctl daemon-reload to recognize the unit file and sudo systemctl enable bt_workaround to put it to work.

(Adapted from this Reddit comment, with some improvements of my own added.)
